# Why does getter not return the value

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex, vuex-modules

I have a getter that returns array of objects. The porblem is that I need past and actual warnings in different components.

It return only actual warning and ignoring past. But when I removing the map method it works correctly.

P.S I tried to split this getter in two getters

```
getPastOrActualWarnings: state => type => {
    const now = +new Date()
    let warnings
    if (type === 'actual') {
        warnings = state.warnings.filter(item => item.time * UNIX_TIMESTAMP > now)
    } else if (type === 'past') {
        warnings = state.warnings.filter(item => item.time * UNIX_TIMESTAMP < now)
    } else {
        warnings = []
    }

    return warnings.map(dateToString)
}

function dateToString (item) {
    item.time = new Date(item.time * UNIX_TIMESTAMP).toLocaleDateString('ru-RU', DATE_OPTIONS)
    return item
}
```

Comment: It looks like you no issue. Did you tried debugging type value.
Try console.log(type);

Comment: @SameerAhmad I invoke the function like that
  `getPastWarnings () {
   return this.$store.getters.getPastOrActualWarnings('past')
  }`

Comment: @SameerAhmad the problem is in the `warnings.map(dateToString)`. It works correctly without map

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are modifying the state directly with your getter, which is something you should never do. The following line modifies `item.time`, which you previously used to sort the items. `item` is a reference to the object that is stored in the state.

```
item.time = new Date(item.time * UNIX_TIMESTAMP).toLocaleDateString('ru-RU', DATE_OPTIONS)
```

To solve the issue, you can do one of two things:

- Use a different name for your rendered time

  ```
  item.renderedTime = new Date(item.time * UNIX_TIMESTAMP).toLocaleDateString('ru-RU', DATE_OPTIONS)
  ```
- (Shallow) copy the item so you are modifying a local copy, rather than the one in the state

  ```
  function dateToString(item) {
    const localItem = { ...item };
    localItem.time = new Date(item.time * UNIX_TIMESTAMP).toLocaleDateString(
      "ru-RU"
    );
    return localItem;
  }
  ```